# Rewind problem after convert *.mp3 to *.aac

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, mp3, whatsapp, aac

I need to prepare audio files in MP3 format for sending via WhatsApp to Android and iOS devices with the ability to pause and mainly **rewind**.

To do this, I use the **ffmpeg** utility on my notebook with Linux Ubuntu installed. Conversion example is described in detail here [FFmpeg command to convert MP3 to AAC](https://superuser.com/questions/370625/ffmpeg-command-to-convert-mp3-to-aac).

As a result, I get AAC audio files that cannot be rewound in the WhatsApp player. I tried to set different options that are responsible for the output sound quality, size, and so on. But the ability to rewind in the WhatsApp player disappears.

I also used the following online services:

1. [ONLINE-CONVERT](https://audio.online-convert.com/)
2. [Convertio](https://convertio.co/)
3. [ZAMZAR](https://www.zamzar.com/).

One of the first two in some cases saves files with the ability to rewind, but in most cases - without it. And it very likely depends on the original file size. This is a hypothesis - if the size is small, then it is possible to rewind the audio file in the WhatsApp player. In any case, this method is not universal.

Please provide a universal solution to the task at hand - a CLI utility or a tool that would convert MP3 to AAC with the ability to rewind in the WhatsApp player. And please indicate which characteristics are responsible for the absence / presence of such functionality.

Comment: Rewind - is to slide by finger the circular slider in the WhatsApp audio player widget.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a bug with WhatsApp?  "rewind" is not a property or function of MP3 or AAC files.

Comment: I dont know. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @VitalyVesyolko Are you saving your files as *.m4a or *.aac?